# Doubts about THorzScrollBox operation

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I have one `THorzScrollBox` with three `TGridLayout`s :

[image]

1. How do I see GridLayout2 at the start of the application?
2. Can I move it around with the mouse (`ShowScrollBars=false`)?
3. Can I tell when some GridLayout totally occupies the screen (`Align=Client` [Rectangle])?

Comment: Instead of a GridLayout I should use a GridPanelLayout and play with percent 
but without any scrollbox. I don't know if this solution apply to your need

Comment: Really, whether it is a `GridLayout` or a `GridPaneLayouts` does not matter, the doubt is about the operation of the `THorzScrollBox`,thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your goal is, but there are a few ways to do this.

**Roll your own with scroll bar**

On the scroll box, place a `TLayout` that is the full height of the scroll box (without the scroll bar), and positioned in the top left corner (`Position.X=0; Position.Y=0`).

I'm assuming that the `TGridLayout` controls are all the same width, and for this explanation I'll assume that they are 300 pixels wide.

Make the width of the `TLayout` the sum of the widths of the `TGridLayout`, i.e 900 pixels.

Set the alignment of each `TGridLayout` to `Left`.

**Roll your own without a scroll bar**

Follow the steps above, but simply substitute a `TLayout` (or other suitable control) for the scroll box, and set `ClipChildren` to `True`.

**Questions for Roll your own**

To answer each of your questions:

1. In the `OnCreate` event handler, set the `TLayout`'s `X` position to -300. (This will show the second `TGridLayout`)
2. Only by implementing your own mouse drag routine.  Code for that can be found in other places on the Internet.  You'll want to move the `TLayout` that is holding the `TGridLayout`s.  Alternatively, provide buttons to click that will (like in the `OnCreate` event handler), set the `TLayout`'s `X` position in the buttons' `OnClick` handlers.
3. Only by comparing the `TLayout`'s `X` position to be one of 0, 300, or 600, although that's not necessary if you move it by the user clicking buttons.

**Use a `TTabControl`**

In the sample files that come with Delphi, there is one called `TabSlideTransition`.  You put your controls (such as your `TGridLayout`s on the different tab pages, and the user can use the mouse to swipe to the previous/next page via an animation where one page slides in to replace the other sliding out.  (The sample file has buttons to click, but dragging also works.)

**Questions for the `TTabControl` option**

To answer each of your questions:

1. In the `OnCreate` event handler, set the active tab number.
2. Yes.
3. The tab will always fill the rectangle. That is, you can't have half of one tab and half of the next.